# Button x:Name="btnBack" not navigating to previous page

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am developing Xamarin Forms application for IOS and Android.I have the list of 3 xamarin form pages say `X.xaml, Y.xaml, Z.xaml`. Page `X.xaml, Y.xaml` is having 1 and click on that button it opens the next-next Xamarin form. And last on `Z.xaml` having 2 buttons `btnBack` & `btnConfirm`

```
<Button x:Name="btnBack"></Button>
<Button x:Name="btnConfirm"></Button>
```

when I click on that back button I want to navigate it to my previous page, but I don't want it like Navigation Back Button or Hardware Back Button click.
for this I have tried this code this will not work.

Z.xaml.cs

```
public partial class Z : ContentPage
        {
            public Z()
            {
                InitializeComponent();                   
                btnBack.Clicked += btnBack_Clicked;
            }   
            private void btnBack_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                var existingPages = Navigation.NavigationStack.ToList();
                foreach (var page in existingPages)
                {
                    if(page == this)
                        Navigation.RemovePage(page);
                }
            }
        }
```

In this code when I click on `Back Button` it Navigate me to prevoius page ie `Y.xaml` once I click on button which is on `Y.xaml` and open the `Z.xaml` page it shows me blank.

`Y.xaml.cs`

```
 public partial class Y: ContentPage
      {
        public Y()
         {
            InitializeComponent();
            btnZ.Clicked += btnZ_Clicked;
          } 
         void btnZ_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
           {            
              Navigation.PushAsync(new Z());
            }
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Kowalski had the right answer however it is incomplete.

You have to `await Navigation.PopAsync()` otherwise you may mess up the navigation stack. So always await it. Example:

```
async void btnBack_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Navigation.PopAsync();
}
```

Beside that be aware that there are bugs in Xamarin.Forms related to navigation, here is one that might be interesting for you as well: 
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=59172

P.S.: Here you can find the official guide on [Popping Pages from the Navigation Stack](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical/#Popping_Pages_from_the_Navigation_Stack).

Comment: having the same issue gives me error System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: Debug your code and share the stacktrace. Where does the exception is thrown? Most probably it is not navigation related.

Comment: I would suggest to review your question, since the original question is different form the current question. Your code examples are incomplete an description is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

you should invoke `Navigation.PopAsync()` to go back

Comment: I tried  PopAsync() after 2-3 times click on btnBack_Clicked and btnZ_Clicked then Z.xaml page will be blank no more Back and Confirm button not displayed. gives me error System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object